# How can I replace a clip with another one in Kdenlive?

Tags: kdenlive

I would like to replace a specific clip inside a project with another one from the project bin but keep all applied effects and the length of the original clip.

[image]

Can this be done in Kdenlive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which effects you have with your clip, but you can readily delete the unwanted clip by placing the cursor over it, left click (it should get a red enclosing marker) and then use the "delete" key to delete it. You should then be free to insert your new clip into the space on the timeline, it can be expanded to fill the empty space by clicking the cursor on the edge and dragging to the desired width. I usually find transitions carry over, but it's probably best to delete them and re-do them for the new clip. Try it, and check your effects while at it. Good luck.

Comment: That is not a solution, and not even a workaround. In my case, I have 125 clips that need replacing with their stabilized versions, and they all have very exact positions and lengths etc. Doing what you suggest, is precisely equal do makes the whole thing from scratch again. :/

Answer (score 4):

The inability to easily replace the footage of a clip while retaining the effect stack and transitions is a pretty big limitation that I've run into as well.  I found a work-around that works as long as your clips are video files and not image sequences.  If you move the source clips before starting kdenlive, then when you open your project, kdenlive won't be able to find them and will present you with a list of clips that it can't find, which will be all the ones that you moved.

I found that you can double-click on each entry in the list and navigate to your new (in this case, stabilized) footage and select it.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with image sequence clips because it doesn't present the correct dialog box for that.  I might try directly editing the kdenlive file and see if that works..

Comment: Great trick, never thought of it

Answer (score 2):

In "project bin", right click on the clip and you gonna find replace clip menu item and find new clip in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I can think of is naming the original clip abc_original.format and replacing the stabilized clip as ABC.format. Then restart Kdenlive. This might cause problems but it worked for me with a few audio files.

Answer (score 1):

"You could try opening the project file in a text or xml editor. And then you could do a search and replace and replace your old clip name with your new stabilised clip name.

Do this on a copy of your project file of course"

Stolen from [this website](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=265&t=114392)

It worked for me!